# Can you 离开 a person? (as in physically separate from them?)

Tags: vocabulary

I'm interested in the usage of the term 离开 as in " to leave". If, for example, I was traveling with another person on the underground (train) and I left them/we separated (to take different trains) would it be considered

我离开他？

Comment: There's a book called [*谢谢你离开我*](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E8%B0%A2%E8%B0%A2%E4%BD%A0%E7%A6%BB%E5%BC%80%E6%88%91/10567848).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, but I probably would use 分开 in your example if I wanted to emphasise the fact that `we separated` (and that it was a mutual act). For instance:

> 我们在那个地铁站分开，因为他要去医院而我要去百货商店。
>
> We separated at the train station, because he needed to go to the hospital, but I needed to go to the department store.

But saying `离开某人` can also work. For instance, when the separation is more "one-sided" (in terms of how it's described), it makes sense to use 离开. For example:

> 我离开我妈妈之后，我去了加拿大读研究生院。
>
> After I left my mother, I went to Canada to attend graduate school.

At the very least, this usage makes sense to me as a semi-native speaker of Chinese. *Notice that the connotations of 离开 and 分开 are somewhat different.* Moreover, 分开 wouldn't be used with an object to state `A left B` - rather, it would be used to state `A and B separated`.

I could also use `离开` in the original setting as well, but mostly in situations similar to the one I described above. For instance:

> 在地铁站离开他之后，我去了百货商店。
>
> 我在那个地铁站离开我朋友，因为我要去厕所。

But `我离开他` (as a sentence in itself) sounds odd without any appropriate qualifications to the statement. Moreover, using `离开` to state something like `我在地铁站离开他，因为我们坐不同的地铁线` sounds odd to me (because the subordinate clause focuses on `我们`）.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds weird. **分开** is a lot better.

Your sentence would be 我们分开了 - we split up - and not *I left him*.

**Oxford**

> VERB
>
> 1 不聚在一起 part
>
> 人群分开让他通过。
>
> The crowd parted to let him through.
>
> 2 使分开 separate
>
> 分开两个拳击手
>
> separate two boxers
>
> 政企分开
>
> separate government from enterprise
>
> 这两件事要分开来解决。
>
> These two issues should be dealt with separately.

Answer (score 1):

It seems  分开 can be used with preposition／coverb ＂跟＂to refer to who is being left（departed from），but then it may sound more sentimental（？）just as 离开：跟人，物或地方分开： 我跟他分开了
cf。【 跟她分开 】 【 歌词 】，＂和＂ is also possible：和姐姐分开对约翰来说有好处。
iciba，has examples of 离开＜某人＞ but only in the sense of 离开（关系亲密的人）
1. VERB 离开（某处或某人）：我就是受不了要离开我的小女儿。3. VERB 抛下，离弃（配偶）；离开（关系亲密的人）他不会离开你的，你不用担心。要是比尔为了别的女人离开我，我会醋意大发。